# RenderTargetBitmap with format rgba32

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I am not very familiar with bitmaps and I need to save a `FrameworkElement` (specificaly `Grid`) as bitmap and copy it to buffer. The problem is I need to save it in Rgba format, not Pgrba, which isn't supported in `RenderTargetBitmap`. Relevant code is here:

```
_targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(xres, yres, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
_targetBitmap.Clear();
// Child is grid
_targetBitmap.Render(Child);
// copy the pixels into the buffer
_targetBitmap.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, xres, yres), bufferPtr, _bufferSize, _stride);
```

I tried using WriteableBitmap, but I didn't how to render the Child. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently, WPF does not support Rgba32 at all. So how should a WriteableBitmap help here?

Comment: Oh, I thought it does. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CopyPixels function is already giving you direct access to the pixel data, so all you need to do is convert between formats.  In this case, you need to swap the channel orders around and undo the premultiplication of alpha values.

NOTE: This code assumes your bufferPtr is a byte array or a byte pointer.

```
for (int y = 0; y < yres; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xres; x++)
    {
        // Calculate array offset for this pixel
        int offset = y * _stride + x * 4;

        // Extract individual color channels from pixel value
        int pb = bufferPtr[offset];
        int pg = bufferPtr[offset + 1];
        int pr = bufferPtr[offset + 2];
        int alpha = bufferPtr[offset + 3];

        // Remove premultiplication
        int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
        if (alpha > 0)
        {
            r = pr * 255 / alpha;
            g = pg * 255 / alpha;
            b = pb * 255 / alpha;
        }

        // Write color channels in desired order
        bufferPtr[offset] = (byte)r;
        bufferPtr[offset + 1] = (byte)g;
        bufferPtr[offset + 2] = (byte)b;
        bufferPtr[offset + 3] = (byte)alpha;
    }
}
```